# For $a,b,c<1$. Minimize $M=\frac{a^2\left(1-2b\right)}{b}+\frac{b^2\left(1-2c\right)}{c}+\frac{c^2\left(1-2a\right)}{a}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, radicals, fractions, maxima-minima

For $0<a,b,c<1$ and $ab+bc+ca=1$, minimize $$M=\frac{a^2\left(1-2b\right)}{b}+\frac{b^2\left(1-2c\right)}{c}+\frac{c^2\left(1-2a\right)}{a}$$

---

**My Try:**
From $ab+bc+ca=1\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{3}\leq a+b+c<3$

We have: $M=\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}-2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)$

$\ge\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)^2}{a+b+c}-2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)-4\left(ab+bc+ca\right)+4\left(ab+bc+ca\right)$

$=a+b+c-2(a+b+c)^2+4 (1)$

Let $a+b+c=x (\sqrt {3}\leq x<3)$

We find Min of function $y=-2x^2+x+4$

And $y_{Min}=-2+\sqrt {3}$ when $x=\sqrt {3}$

Right or Wrong ?

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong, but the answer is indeed, $\sqrt3-2$. Now, I am looking for a nice proof for all positive numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $ab+ac+bc=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.
Hence, $M=\sqrt3-2$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$. Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}-\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}}\geq(\sqrt3-2)\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}$$ or
$$\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}-\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\right)\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$$ or
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}-a-b+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}-\frac{b^2}{a}-c+a+b+c-\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq2((a-b)^2+(c-a)(c-b))$$ or
$$\frac{(a-b)^2(a+b)}{ab}+\frac{(c-a)(c^2-b^2)}{ac}+a+b+c-\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\geq$$
$$\geq2((a-b)^2+(c-a)(c-b))$$ or
$$(a-b)^2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}-2\right)+(c-a)(c-b)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{b}{ac}-2\right)+a+b+c-\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\geq0,$$
which is true because $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}-2>0$, $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{b}{ac}-2\geq\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a}-2>0$ and
$$a+b+c-\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}=\frac{(a-b)^2+(c-a)(c-b)}{a+b+c+\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}}\geq0.$$
Done!

The inequality
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}-\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}}\geq(\sqrt3-2)\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}$$ 
is true for all positives $a$, $b$ and $c$, but my proof of the last statement is very ugly.

Comment: do you have other answer ?

Comment: "c=min{a,b,c}" ? i don't know

Comment: @Uchiha Itachi The inequality is cyclic, which says we can assume that $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: @Word Shallow I am ready to explain. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that $$M=\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}-2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq -2+\sqrt{3} (*)$$
or equivalently
$$\left ( \frac{a^2}{b}-2a+b \right )+\left ( \frac{b^2}{c}-2b+c \right )+\left ( \frac{c^2}{a}-2c+a \right )+(a+b+c-\sqrt{3})-2(a^2+b^2+c^2-1)\geq 0.$$

We have
$$\sum_{cyc} \left (\frac{a^2}{b}-2a+b\right)=\frac{(a-b)^2}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{c}+\frac{(c-a)^2}{a}$$
$$a+b+c-\sqrt{3}=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-3}{a+b+c+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}{2(a+b+c+\sqrt{3})}$$
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2-1)=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)=(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2.$$

Hence 
$$(*) \Leftrightarrow (a-b)^2\left [ \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{2(a+b+c+\sqrt{3})}-1 \right ]+(b-c)^2\left [ \frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{2(a+b+c+\sqrt{3})}-1 \right ]+(c-a)^2\left [ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2(a+b+c+\sqrt{3})}-1 \right ]\geq 0 $$

This true because $\frac{1}{a};\frac{1}{b};\frac{1}{c}>1$ when $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$